# can't create pull request from bitbucket pipelines

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to set up a step in my pipelines where I can automatically raise a pull request from develop branch to master branch (as part of the release process). However, I cannot seem to find the solution when using with [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests?_ga=2.198229679.1473888840.1582892069-236431429.1564599520) REST API pull request . The problem, is because the curl command is running in pipelines environment with bitbucket-pipelines user, and I have no idea what is the password for this user. is this something even possible? like does bitbucket provide its pipelines user password ? I couldn't find anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an App password for the user that is supposed to raise the pull request. (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html)
You can then inject username and password as a variable into pipelines. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html Make sure to make that variable a secured variable so the password can't be viewed!